# How to insert elements in array within a for loop in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, insert, tableview

I'm trying to populate a table view with potential information from a series of arrays.  What I want for them to get listed in index by order.  It's a top 10 list, so if an element doesn't exist at a certain time it should skip it.  I can do this with array.append.  I'm trying with array.insertAtIndex and getting "fatal error: Array out of range".  Here is my code........

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
        query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (vid:Array?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if vid != nil
            {
                for items in vid!
                {

                    if let myfav1 = items["vid1"] as? NSArray
                    {
                        let id = myfav1[0] as! String
                        let rank = myfav1[1] as! String
                        let title = myfav1[2] as! String
                        let description = myfav1[3] as! String
                        let image = myfav1[4] as! String
                        self.vidRankArray.insert(rank, atIndex: 0)
                        self.vidIdArray.insert(id, atIndex: 0)
                        self.vidTitleArray.insert(title, atIndex: 0)
                        self.vidDescriptionArray.insert(description, atIndex: 0)
                        self.vidImageArray.insert(image, atIndex: 0)

                    }
                    if let myfav2 = items["vid2"] as? NSArray
                    {
                        let id = myfav2[0] as! String
                        let rank = myfav2[1] as! String
                        let title = myfav2[2] as! String
                        let description = myfav2[3] as! String
                        let image = myfav2[4] as! String
                        self.vidRankArray.insert(rank, atIndex: 1)
                        self.vidIdArray.insert(id, atIndex: 1)
                        self.vidTitleArray.insert(title, atIndex: 1)
                        self.vidDescriptionArray.insert(description, atIndex: 1)
                        self.vidImageArray.insert(image, atIndex: 1)
                    }
                    if let myfav3 = items["vid3"] as? NSArray
                    {
                        let id = myfav3[0] as! String
                        let rank = myfav3[1] as! String
                        let title = myfav3[2] as! String
                        let description = myfav3[3] as! String
                        let image = myfav3[4] as! String
                        self.vidRankArray.insert(rank, atIndex: 2)
                        self.vidIdArray.insert(id, atIndex: 2)
                        self.vidTitleArray.insert(title, atIndex: 2)
                        self.vidDescriptionArray.insert(description, atIndex: 2)
                        self.vidImageArray.insert(image, atIndex: 2)

                    }
```

and I'm getting my number of rows like this.....

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return self.vidIdArray.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only insert an item to index 0 of an empty array, not 1, 2, or otherwise. Similarly, if you have 1 item in an array(at index 0), you can only insert an object at index 0 or index 1.

It sounds like you want to use the array as *n* empty spaces which you can selectively fill, and that is not how this type of array works.